# Import existing Swing project to NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have been sent a Java file containing a GUI interface that I have to edit and add features. I have created a project on NetBeans and I am able to launch it. The problem is I can't edit the interface, and all the documentation I have found is about creating a new interface. So I would like to know if there is a way to edit the interface of the project with NetBeans. I am using NetBeans 7.2 on Linux.

Comment: Java code is Java code. You edit the file by typing new Java instructions inside the file. If what you want to do is use the GUI "wysiwyg" editor of NetBeans, and you don't have the NetBeans-proprietary files containing the GUI definition, then AFAIK, you're doomed. But are you sure the Java code was generated with this wysiwyg editor in the first place? If so, why don't you ask the guy who asked you to enhance the GUI to provide this file as well? My advice: stay away from this wysiwyg editor, and code your GUI by hand. You'll save time in the end, and your code will be more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually started by hard coding the file they sent me with Eclipse, but I got stucked so I thought that would be a good idea to use NetBean GUI. So maybe I should create another topic about my issue.

Comment: Yes indeed. If you don't know how to do something by hand, the GUI tool won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I would like to know if there is a way to edit the interface of the project with NetBeans.

Yes there is.  But not using the 'form designer' or whatever Netbeans is calling it now.  It requires actual knowledge of coding Java.

Comment: Thanks that's what JB Nizet advised me too and I was able to do it after reading the java doc.

Comment: *"I was able to do it"*  Glad you got it sorted & +1 for being able to solve it from tips.  :)

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy people: 
Open the old swing on the design tab, select all the items, copy and paste into the new swing file. 
and voila..
It is also import the code from the old file (everything that is related to the swing elements).
I hope it helps